# Python module not callable when importing getopt

Tags: python, getopt

I am new to python and the getopt function. I am trying to import getopt, however I run into an error.

My code is literally just:

```
import getopt
```

and also tried

```
from getopt import *   /// from getopt import getopt
```

Output below:

```
python asdfasdf.py
ARGV      : []
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "asdfasdf.py", line 1, in <module>
    import getopt
  File "/home/STUDENTS/~~/csc328/TCP/pyExample/getopt.py", line 12, in <module>
    'version=',
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

My python is 2.6 something and this was implemented in 2.3 I believe.

edit:  I'm using unix

Comment: you might be have `getotp` module in your code. When you refere python third party module, it try to import your module. Please give code of `/home/STUDENTS/grobe258/csc328/TCP/pyExample/getopt.py`

Comment: Thank you, that file was causing the issue. I had named my file getopt in order to distinguish it. I deleted the code but I still got the error, however I made a new directory and it is working fine, thank you.

Comment: There most likely was a `.pyc` file still lying around.

Comment: @Greg, I am posting same answer in answer, please accept it, so if someone face problem he can see the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you might be have getotp module in your code. When you refere python third party module, it try to import your module.

Pleas remove `getopt.py` in your example or rename it.